# Frozen store-bought pie crust

Tags: pie, crust, frozen

I have a store-bought frozen pie crust but no directions.  Do I need to do anything to the crust (pre-bake?) to use it for a pumpkin pie?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, pumpkin pie is made in an unbaked crust. So just pull your frozen shell out of the freezer and let it come to room temperature before filling, and bake it per your recipe.

EDIT: I looked at a few recipes, and some do call for prebaking the crust, so let the recipe be your guide. The most common recipe, the one from back of the most popular brand of canned pumpkin, calls for filling the unbaked shell.

Comment: I agree; it depends on the recipe.  As much as I like doing things from scratch, I can't work a rolling pin to save my life.  Pre-made crusts taste fine, and are much easier to work with.